# VS Code arduino plugin, not compiling the additional source code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino, avr-gcc

For a project for school, I am programming a UAV with an Arduino Mega 2560 as the brains. To program it, I am using Visual Studio code, with the Arduino extension provided by Microsoft.

To keep the code readable, I have a main.ino file, with each separate self written library in their own folder. Like this:

-UAV
---Main.ino
---ToF
-----ToF.cpp
-----Tof.h
---PowerProtection
-----PowerProtection.h
---MotorControl
-----MotorControl.cpp
-----MotorControl.h

When verifying the code, I get the following error message:

```
[Starting] Verifying sketch 'ArduinoMain.ino'
Please see the build logs in output path: d:\Documenten\Documents\GitHub\build
Loading configuration...
Initializing packages...
Preparing boards...
Verifying...
C:\Users\larsh\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIQryfg.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `setup':
d:\Documenten\Documents\GitHub\UAV/ArduinoMain.ino:12: undefined reference to `MotorControl::setPowerSetup(float, float, float, float)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
IntelliSense configuration already up to date. To manually rebuild your IntelliSense configuration run "Ctrl+Alt+I"
[Error] Verifying sketch 'ArduinoMain.ino': Exit with code=1
```

I know this error comes forth from the fact that the compiler is not compiling the additional source codes. So how can I add the additional files to the compiler, while also keeping a clear structure?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-arduino/issues/271 TL;DR you can't.

Comment: found a way around this, by adding an include to the sourcecode itself at the bottom of the header file.

Comment: Well if you are willing to call that clear structure, sure, go ahead.